# prediction with cross sectional data

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, predictive-models, prediction, cross-section

I have learned linear regression for a long time but obviously not good enough so this question may seem naive.

Let's say using historical data from time 0 to time T we construct the linear regression model $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \dots +\beta_nX_n$. And let's assume $Y$ and $X$'s have time series data. So when we try to predict $Y_{T+1}$, if I am correct, we plug in values of $X_{T+1}$'s into the estimated model. However, if in reality, the values of $Y$ and $X$'s manifest at the same time, it would have no point to do the prediction since $Y_{T+1}$ comes out at the same time as $X$'s.

So my question is that in this kind of situation, what can we do to remedy this problem? Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: How did the index T enter the problem.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Oh, sorry. I should have mentioned that $Y$ and $X$'s have time series data. Let's say $Y$ is the time series of a stock's return and $X$'s could be GDP, the S&P 500 index, etc.. Thank you.